# Update browser address bar without reload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url

I like the way facebook changes the URL of the browser address bar when you scroll between images, and how it works on IE7. However, I've only found information on how to do it on HTML5 browsers, and I want to support IE7.

As this is a HTML5 solution, the following:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

is not an option if there's another solution available.

**EDIT**

Before any hashes.

But is there?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Comment: The only solution I know of for this without html5 is [history.js](https://github.com/fortes/history.js/), but it only supports IE8+, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only other option I'm aware of involves using the `#hash` fragment to determine the "url" or "state" of the page using the `hashchange` event, which is not supported in IE7:

http://caniuse.com/#search=hashchange

However, there are polyfills:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

It's a rather hacky approach and it breaks HTTP protocol since it *relies* on javascript to output the correct content, but you may not care about that:

http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

`History.js` claims cross-browser support, although I haven't used it (uses history for HTML5 browsers, hashchange for older ones):

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, but I need to change the url before the hash. Would this do it?

Comment: @Christian: Without support for the History API, that is impossible

Comment: That's one of the problems using the "hashbang" technique, your urls may end up like `example.com/posts/post1#!posts/post2`... there are really a lot of problems with it. Basically the "actual url" typically *is* the entire hash fragment.

Comment: Basically I'm going to use this when user clicks a certain link, and new content is loaded in iframe, so the url is not changed, and makes it impossible to link to a certain page.

Comment: At least your back and forward buttons will work using an iframe. You can always use a "share" link that has the correct URL. People will generally use those instead of copy/pasting the address bar. I will just say in case it's not clear, I don't recommend any solution that involves reading the hash fragment. Use history where you can and tell IE to go screw.

Comment: Yeah, but in case of a refresh, the page is lost.

Comment: You could perhaps use cookies/session to retrieve and load the last page back into the iframe to solve the "refresh" issue. I'm aware of all the pitfalls and issues you're trying to cope with, there's no particularly easy solution if you want full IE support.

Comment: I really don't know about that. It's a 4chan clone I'm using, and I simply want to show the current url :)

Comment: I don't know what the best solution is for your particular project (of which I know very few details), the question was pretty general. Go ahead and use the hash approach if you want or try history.js. There's no way to do this cleanly in IE7, 8, or 9 - sorry.

Comment: But how facebook does it then? I just tested it, and it works perfectly. I really don't care if it's just a "dirty hack" or doesn't validate, if it just works.

Comment: Facebook uses hashbang for IE7. All the URLs are like `http://www.facebook.com/#!/actual/url`. It also appears that when you paste a hashbang URL into the address bar in an HTML5 browser, they redirect to the real URL (once again, reliant on javascript since the server cannot read hash fragments).