# changing URL into clicked elements on the page without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

[Update browser address bar without reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13919848/6084519)
I found this about making the URL change without updating.

I want to make a website like
http://fancytext.blogspot.ie/

but instead of adding the symbols to the text box there I want the symbols to overwrite the URL on the address bar is this possible with javascript or ruby?

Comment: If you want to do it the right way so then you should learn **Angular JS** as because that is the perfect thing for your desired thing but that is more than just what you are looking for..!

Comment: or go with pjax, which is ajax + push state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "push" any text into the address bar using pushState and it's simple like hell:

```
window.history.pushState({url: yourUrl}, null, yourUrl);
```

remember:

you could use full address, when you try to push url, other ways the path in url will be appended to current url, when you try to use slashes (if I remember correctly)

Working example is my own site, where address is changing while you scrolling thru page http://dariuszm.pl (may not work on older browsers)

Comment: but can you delete the whole                                                            http://www.dariuszm.pl/scrapping   and have just 'scrapping' and when you add another one you will have 'scrapping'  + 'jumping'                                   without any www.xyz.com , is that possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible for security reasons. At least chrome and FF block that action. Pushed url must be consistent with document.origin

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible.  You simply need to put a hash (`#`) before your symbol.  Anything after the `#` does not result in a page change.

You can easily set it without JavaScript by the `href` in an `a` tag...

```
<a href="#Ⓐ">Ⓐ</a>
```

But if you're desperate to use JavaScript, it can be done there as well...

```
<script>
    location.hash = '#Ⓐ';
</script>
```